# Is there a shorter way to initialize an array of structs?

Tags: c, struct, microchip

I have a "buffer of buffers" like this:

```
#define BUFFER_MESSAGE_COUNT 5

unsigned char buffer_data[BUFFER_MESSAGE_COUNT][128];

typedef struct {
    unsigned char *data;
    int size;
    int cursor;
} t_buffer;

typedef struct {
    int cursor;
    int size;
    t_buffer buffers[BUFFER_MESSAGE_COUNT];
} t_message_buffer;

t_message_buffer message_buffer = {
    0,
    BUFFER_MESSAGE_COUNT,
    {
        { buffer_data[0], sizeof(buffer_data[0]) / sizeof(char), 0 },
        { buffer_data[1], sizeof(buffer_data[1]) / sizeof(char), 0 },
        { buffer_data[2], sizeof(buffer_data[2]) / sizeof(char), 0 },
        { buffer_data[3], sizeof(buffer_data[3]) / sizeof(char), 0 },
        { buffer_data[4], sizeof(buffer_data[4]) / sizeof(char), 0 }
    }
};
```

Is there a shorter/better way to declare and initialize it than giving all the elements?

I am using the Microchip XC8 compiler, but the question is probably universal.

Comment: Define "shorter" and "better". The initialization above will not cost you any additional execution time or memory space, because `message_buffer` is a global variable located in the data-section of the executable. This means that the executable image will contain a "piece" of hard-coded values, which will be loaded into memory by the OS (along with the rest of the image) every time you run the program. If that variable was a local variable (in a function), then the initialization would take place every time the function was executed.

Comment: You could avoid dividing by `sizeof(char)` since that is always 1.

Comment: I meant "shorter" in terms of lines of code, not in execution time.

Comment: @barakmanos except if you boot straight from an EEPROM in a barebone microcontroller environment, which is very likely if you're using a microchip compiler.

Comment: You can drop this monster: `sizeof(buffer_data[0]) / sizeof(char)`. Observe that the size of your arrays is always 128, a constant, so you can improve your code by defining a constant for this size: `#define ARRSIZE   128`. On the other hand, sizeof(char) always is 1, because the standard C rules. Then, you would have, for example: `{ buffer_data[0], ARRSIZE, 0 },`. For the main question, an initializer function seems to be the best choice, as other folks said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you are using is fine, but it's not very adaptable.  A `for` loop would be better:

```
t_message_buffer message_buffer;

message_buffer.cursor = 0;
message_buffer.size = BUFFER_MESSAGE_COUNT;
for(int i = 0; i < BUFFER_MESSAGE_COUNT; i++)
{
    message_buffer.buffers[i].data = buffer_data[i];
    message_buffer.buffers[i].size = sizeof(buffer_data[i]);
    message_buffer.buffers[i].cursor = 0;
}
```

This way, if the value of `BUFFER_MESSAGE_COUNT` changes, you won't have to adjust many places in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are working in an environment where size does matter (for a change).

If it's the case, I'm not quite sure it is an efficient way of initializing a RAM structure.
This will force the compiler to allocate an identical amount of ROM for pre-main static variables initialization.

Since the contents of your structure seems fairly redundant, using an initializer function would likely be more efficient in terms of resource usage, and certainly more readable and evolutive than an initializer macro.

All things being equal, I would simply go for an initializer function.

Comment: Since everything is 0, can I just do `for (i = 0 ; i < sizeof(buffer_data) ; i++) *(&buffer_data + i) = 0;`?

Comment: I would rather go for a `memset (message_buffer, 0, sizeof(message_buffer));` and then set the few non-zero fields on top of the freshly zeroed structure.

Comment: Oh, I see, of course the pointers aren't 0. I don't think I have memset() available, but the `for` should do the same.

Comment: I would advise you to provide a memset or bzero function yourself if you are unlucky enough to work in a real barebone environment. However, I'm a bit surprised to find an embedded compiler in 2014 that does not support such useful and lightweight parts of stdlib.

Comment: Ok, it does, if you include the correct string.h (which I at first didn't).

Comment: Well most of the compilers I used back in the mid-90's did, so I expected as much from your cutting edge brand new toy :).

Comment: By the way, when I leave out the initialization (everything from `=` to `};`), the ROM usage actually gets 40 bytes higher while the RAM usage stays the same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45032/discussion-between-kuroi-neko-and-andrekr)

Comment: is that system using something like a stack frame? — is your fragment outside everything (i.e. is it global or "local to a file")? If so, to me it's nonsense to initialize data by code and it's better you keep your source as it is, if your worry is about memory saving, since the compiler should produce no extra code for the initialization. But you can know what's goig on with your compiler if it can dump the code in source form, as `gcc -S` would do. Can it?

Comment: In a barebone environment, the compiler will produce no extra code indeed, but will eat up ROM to provide an initializer to each and every initialized static. I did participate in the design and coding of quite a few embedded applications, and I can insure you there are cases where studying the question is anything but nonsensical.